# gnome-disk-utility not showing all partitions after Ubuntu 16.04 clean-install

Tags: 16.04, mount, gparted, gnome-disk-utility

After a clean-install of 16.04 alongside W7 my shared partitions did not auto-mount at boot. I opened "disk" in launcher and surprisingly the partitions are not like shown in gparted (and in reality) and as a result I cannot tell the gnome-disk-utility to automount them.

- gnome-disk-utility 3.18.3.1
- UDisks 2.1.7 (compilato su 2.1.6)
- `df -h | grep -e '^/'`:

  ```
  /dev/sda7        66G  7,0G     56G  12% /
  /dev/sda3       218G  202G     16G  93% /mnt/224C7A834C7A5191
  /dev/sda5       269G  249G     20G  93% /media/mat/HDDati
  ```

[image: "disk" output]

[image: gparted output]

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 596,2 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: xxbxxx7ae0

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2048   31459327  31457280    15G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2  *      31459328   31664127    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3         31664128  487419903 455755776 217,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4        487421950 1250263039 762841090 363,8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        627788133 1190512889 562724757 268,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       1190516736 1250263039  59746304  28,5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7        487421952  627787775 140365824    67G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I solved the problem in some way some time after posting the question. It works now, but I don't remember how I did it. This partition 4 and 5 boundary problem came out only now, though.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX fdisk -l /dev/sda`? Thanks.

Comment: I have *exactly* the same issue as the OP! `gnome-disks` is showing the extended partition of all my 2 hard disks and 1 SSD as "Unknown 0.0kb" none of my logical partitions, their space is shown as a single "Free Space". While `fdisk`, `gparted` and the whole OS works on them just fine...

Comment: I suspect you've found a bug, and perhaps should report it, especially if you can reproduce it. If the problem with automounting shows up again,  I'd assume you could work around it by manually editing /etc/fstab.

Comment: Have you tried editting the fstab entry? You probably should, but if you do so, I recommend using caution

Comment: I _suspect_ the issue has to do with duplicated partition UUIDs, originated from copying partitions using gParted. Once I re-generated all UUIDs and they were unique again, `gnome-disks` showed all logical partitions. Worth investigating...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an abandoned question. OP hasn't signed on in 2017 and cannot respond to new comments. The question has no answers. As per guidelines here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1843/what-to-do-with-abandoned-questions